# Prove that if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$, then $xy \leq |xy|$.

Tags: absolute-value

Prove that if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$, then $xy \leq |xy|$.

Proof (Attempt):

Case $1$ : $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$. Then $xy \geq 0$ so $xy =|xy|$.

Case $2$ : $x \geq 0$ and $y < 0$. Then $xy \leq 0$ so $xy \leq |xy|$.

Case $3$ : $x < 0$ and $y \geq 0$. Then $xy \leq 0$ so $xy \leq |xy|$.

Case $4$ : $x < 0$ and $y < 0$. Then $xy > 0$ so $xy = |xy|$.

This is what I came up with, though I wonder if I should concern the case where either one of them is zero separately as another case. My question is, does this proof seem okay or should I include sub cases to account for when $x$ or $y$ is zero?

Comment: For any $z\in \mathbb R$ we have $z≤|z|$.

Comment: You can instead prove that for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$, $z \leq |z|$, which only requires two cases. Then since $xy \in \mathbb{R}$, it follows that $xy \leq |xy|$. Your proof is correct, though, and already encompasses the cases when $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Comment: $\forall A\in R  -|A|\leq A\leq |A|$.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to mention that if either $x$ or $y$ are $0$, then the product is also $0$, so that $xy = 0 = |0| = |xy|$.  But otherwise, good proof! :)

Comment: I don't see any need to include more cases-- in fact, you could make your proof shorter. Your use of "$\leq 0$" and "$\geq 0$" already account for when your variables are $0$.

Comment: Okay so if one proves that $x \leq |x|$ then we are done because $x$ here is a real number so when you do $xy$, the product is just another real number which then you can apply the previous argument of $x \leq |x|$.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is to use one of the possible definitions  of the absolute value on $\mathbf R$:
$$\lvert a\rvert=\max(a, -a).$$

Comment: OP was asking for someone to review their proof.  Your answer suggests an alternate path to the proof, rather than a review of OP's proof.

Comment: You're right. I think it's better, in absolute value questions, to avoid considering cases when it's possible.

Comment: This doesn't avoid case consideration, you still have to separate between positive and negative to be able to tell what the maximum is.

Comment: Yes, but for this precise  question, it's included in the definition, since $\lvert a\rvert=\max(a,-a)$ implies $a\le \lvert a\rvert$ for any $a$.

Comment: You're correct in this respect.

Comment: I take back what I said. You're using cases in the definition of $\max$.

Comment: Why, yes, but not in proving the O.P.'s inequality. This definition uses cases once and for all. For instance, proving the triangle inequality becomes much simpler.